# Google apps engine - some questions about ImageService url serving

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

GAE Images Service promises very high performance and a huge code semplification, however I'd like to know some additional details about before using it:

1. is the url obtained by getServingUrl persistent? i.e. a static reference to the blobkey representing the image in the blobstore? 
   if it is, then it is better to create it once when a new image is uploaded so as to eventually store also the reverse association blobkey->url right?
2. When I need to delete an image:
   If I remove the blob from the blobkey then the image will be anyway visible from the urlfor max. 24h right?
   If I remove only the url reference using the deleteServingURL method how does the imagesservice behave? same way as before?
   And what if I delete both?
3. Does this service have any additional cost?
4. Is it really efficient and responsive as it says to be?

Answer (score 1):

> is the url obtained by getServingUrl persistent?

yes

> it is better to create it once

yes - it takes time to create the URL so you're best option is to create it and then store the result.

> When I need to delete an image

Call `deleteServinceURL` first and then delete the blobKey as well is the best way.

> Does this service have any additional cost?

You pay for the bandwidth for accessing the URL and a very small amount of blob storage is it generates some thumbnails to increase the serving speed.

> Is it really efficient and responsive as it says to be?

Yes

Comment: thanks for your reply! but even if I delete the url and blob that way I will have to wait max. 24h to have things erased?

Comment: Not that I am aware of - unless you're referring to images stored in intermediate caches? Where did you read you have to wait 24 hours?